# Ubuntu 17.04: Starting up laptop with lid closed

Tags: display, laptop, startup, dock

I'm using my Fujitsu Lifebook E746 laptop on a dock with 2 external monitors, so I'm usually not using the integrated laptop monitor. The problem I'm having is the following:

Starting up the device lid closed from the power button on the dock seems to still have the integrated display active. I can enter login credentials etc. on the external monitors and startup is fine, BUT the display is still on, so i can move windows to that screen, which is pretty annoying.

This can be fixed by opening the lid and closing it again to disable the display, but that's way annoying.

Is there a way to have the integrated display disabled when starting up with the lid closed?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but i use arch linux with xfce4, all i did was disable the monitor completely. the problem is the in built monitor will always be disabled and you cannot use the laptop without the external monitor(s).
[how i did it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utUZu.png)